# Etagger: How to renew between deploys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, browser-cache

I'm having the strangest error using rails 3.2 plus the etagger gem which is part of rails 4. I'm using it on CRUD resources routes controllers alongside #etag calls and #fresh_when. It all works well, until I deploy again. The resources used to validate the cache (the current_user and the controller resources) are of course not updated in between, which makes the browsers render the previously cached page. Problem is, the given cached page has the wrong csrf tags.

How should I properly invalidate the caches in between deploys? Maybe I could use the last_signed_in_at field from the current user (I'm using devise, btw)? And that only seems fair if I assume all users will logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current strategy: I use the latest commit key to invalidate the caching between deploys. This involves a system call on boot, which is (depending of your inclination) both practical and overhead.